# Python numpy keep a list of indices of a sorted 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array and I want to create a new 1D array where it is indices of numbers in the first array if they are sorted in an ascending order. For the following array:

```
A = [[1,0,2],
     [0,3,0]]
```

I want this to be like:

```
B = [[1,1],[0,2],[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,2]]
```

Any idea how it can be done in python using predefined functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to sort the indices of flattened array, followed by [`unravel_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) to convert the flat index back to coordinates:

```
>>> i = (-a).argsort(axis=None, kind='mergesort')
>>> j = np.unravel_index(i, a.shape) 
>>> np.vstack(j).T
array([[1, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2]])
```

`-a` and `kind='mergesort'` is in order to sort the array in a *stable* manner in descending order (to match the output you are looking for).

If you do not care about having a stable sort, replace the first line with:

```
>>> i = a.argsort(axis=None)[::-1]
```

Comment: The tip about using `np.unravel_index` is brilliant!  I am glad to learn this method.

Comment: What do you mean by "stable sort"?  Does this produce consistent sorting for identical values?

Comment: @stvn66 I believe this does produce consistent sorting for identical values which is equal to stable sorting